# Action bar search view in fragment is not working

Tags: android

Here is what I did so far -

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    getActivity().setTitle("DASHBOARD");
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getContext(). getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
        {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtadapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            System.out.println("on text chnge text: "+newText);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
        {
            // this is your adapter that will be filtered
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            System.out.println("on query submit: "+query);
            return true;
        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(textChangeListener);
        }
```

Here code Search view in action bar, it only filter the one name other does not work . The code  `adapter` class code is below . `Actionbar`  doing in `fragment`

```
adapter = new FavouritesAdapter(getContext(),distanceArr,contactName,status,leadDetailsId,addressLine1,addressLine2,city,state,zipCode);
                            list.setAdapter(adapter);
                            list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```